# Tap gesture event not working on UIView

Tags: swift, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am trying to add a tap gesture to a UIView but the gesture is not getting recognized.

"iconBadgeView" is a UIView with an image of defined size as passed in the parameters.

```
lazy var cardioVascularIcon : IconBadgeView! = {

    let iconBadgeView = IconBadgeView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 95, height: 95), data:["big":"db_history"])

    let tapEvent = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(loadNewView(sender:)))

    tapEvent.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    iconBadgeView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    iconBadgeView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true       
    iconBadgeView.addGestureRecognizer(tapEvent)
}()
```

There is a delegator attached to the same class and function is implemented as below :

```
func loadNewView(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)  {
    print("Tapped")
}
```

The function loadNewView is not getting called. I am not sure what is wrong here in the code. Please if someone can help.

I am adding iconBadgeView to the superview as below :

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)

    addSubview(cardioVascularIcon)

    cardioVascularIcon.pinToSuperview([.Top])
    cardioVascularIcon.pinToSuperview([.Left], constant: 92)
    cardioVascularIcon.pinToSuperview([.Right], constant: 92)
}
```

Comment: `let tapEvent = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(loadNewView(sender:)))
    tapEvent.addTarget(iconBadgeView, action: #selector(loadNewView(sender:)))
` why are you repeating yourself here my friend lol. if you were to create a gesture with a `default constructor` meaning `UITapGestureRecognizer()`  then you will need to provide your selector to that method `addTarget`, but since you are using the custom constructor which takes a selector and target so need to have that second line of code :)

Comment: I have tried with removing the duplicate line but it didn't help

Comment: did you get any errors/issue ? just by curiosity did you add that `iconBadgeView` into your superView ? also since you disable `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` make sure you add these constraints to it if now you might think you view in on screen and it is not :)

Comment: No, I am not getting any error as such. I have updated the question with the addsubView logic as used.

Comment: let tapGesture : UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.recognizeTap(sender:))).  try using this Line

Comment: @iOSGeek where did you see ViewController here, In think all this code is within a UIView here, If I am not mistaking here

Comment: ViewController is the name of viereController in which you are declaring tapGesture .  ->  class ViewController: UIViewController ->  I mean by this [ViewController]

Comment: Yeah, as @Lamar said, it is a UIView class.

Comment: @user2122178 does the iconBadgeView gets shown on screen?, since I don't really the reason you are making the iconBadgeView lazy, just make it a normal property then initialize within the `initializer` of the superview and add the gesture there and change this    `super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)` to     `super.init(frame: frame)`

Comment: @user2122178 remove UITapGestureRecognizer from  loadNewView functions and pass nothing when call method, let tapEvent = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.loadNewView))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a workaround for the issue. I have used a button instead of a Label and things are working exactly fine now. Below is the code I am using :

```
func createButton (buttonWidth : CGFloat?, buttonTitle : String?, buttonFont : UIFont?, imageName : String?, buttonColor : UIColor?) -> UIButton {
    let newButton = UIButton(type: . custom)
    newButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = false
    newButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    newButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false

    if let title = buttonTitle {
        newButton.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
    }
    if let color = buttonColor {
        if let _ = newButton.titleLabel {
            newButton.setTitleColor(color, for: .normal)
        }
    }

    if let btnWidth = buttonWidth {
        newButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: btnWidth, height: btnWidth)
        newButton.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * newButton.bounds.size.width
        newButton.clipsToBounds = true
    }
    if let img = imageName {
        newButton.setImage(UIImage(named: img), for: .normal)
    }
    if let font = buttonFont {
        newButton.titleLabel?.font = font
    }

    return newButton
}
let addDiagButton = self.createButton(buttonWidth: nil, buttonTitle: addButtonTitle, buttonFont: UIFont.regularDisplayOfSize(30), imageName: nil, buttonColor: UIColor(red: 111, green: 160, blue: 186))

addDiagButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addDiag(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

The above code has a common function which creates a button and also attaches the trigger event with it. The code is working perctely fine.

To make it behave like a label click, I have added a line in the createButton function.

newButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false

This will restrict the flash effect of the button when clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Your iconBadgeView disappear, because it's local variable.

You must init cardioVascularIcon var.

```
lazy var cardioVascularIcon : IconBadgeView! = {

  cardioVascularIcon.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 95, height: 95)
  //here call function which sets data property

  let tapEvent = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(loadNewView(sender:)))

  tapEvent.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
  cardioVascularIcon.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

  cardioVascularIcon.isUserInteractionEnabled = true       
  cardioVascularIcon.addGestureRecognizer(tapEvent)
}()
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but I am afraid it didn't work.

Comment: It's the view visible on screen?  There is missing code which add this new view to view hierarchy.

Comment: Yeah, The view is visible on the screen.